# MATLAB use custom function with pdist

Tags: matlab, pdist

I have a custom function to calculate the weight between two pixels (that represent nodes on a graph) of an image

```
function [weight] = getWeight(a,b,img, r, L)
    ac = num2cell(a);
    bc = num2cell(b);
    imgint1 = img(sub2ind(size(img),ac{:})); 
    imgint2 = img(sub2ind(size(img),bc{:}));
    weight = (sum((a - b) .^ 2) + (r^2/L) * abs(imgint2 - imgint1)) / (2*r^2);
```

where `a = [x1 y1]` and `b = [x2 y2]` are coordinates that represents pixels of the image, `img` is a gray-scale image and `r` and `L` are constants. Within the function `imgint1` and `imgint2` are gray intensities of the pixels on `a` and `b`.

I need to calculate the weight among set of points of the image.

Instead of two nested loops, I want to use the pdist function because it is WAY FASTER!

For instance, let `nodes` a set of pixel coordinates

```
nodes  =
 1     1
 1     2
 2     1
 2     2
```

And `img =  [ 128 254; 0 255]`, `r = 3`, `L = 255`

In order to get these weights, I am using an intermediate function.

```
function [weight] = fxIntermediate(a,b, img, r, L)

    weight = bsxfun(@(a,b) getWeight(a,b,img,r,L), a, b);
```

In order to finally get the whole set of weights

```
distNodes = pdist(nodes,@(XI,XJ) fxIntermediate(XI,XJ,img,r,L));
```

But it always get me an error

```
Error using pdist (line 373)
Error evaluating distance function '@(XI,XJ)fxIntermediate(XI,XJ,img,r,L)'.

Error in obtenerMatriz (line 27)
    distNodes = pdist(nodes,@(XI,XJ) fxIntermediate(XI,XJ,img,r,L));

Caused by:
    Error using bsxfun
    Invalid output dimensions.
```

**EDIT 1**

This is a short example of my code that it should work, but I got the error mentioned above. If you copy/paste the code on MATLAB and run the code you will see the error

```
function [adjacencyMatrix] = problem
    img = [123, 229; 0, 45];                % 2x2 Image as example
    nodes  = [1     1;  1     2; 2     2];  % I want to calculate distance function getWeight()
                                            % between pixels img(1,1), img(1,2), img(2,2) 
    r = 3;                                  % r is a constant, doesn't matter its meaning
    L = 255;                                % L is a constant, doesn't matter its meaning

    distNodes = pdist(nodes,@(XI,XJ) fxIntermediate(XI,XJ,img,r,L)); 
    adjacencyMatrix = squareform(distNodes );
end

function [weight] = fxIntermediate(a,b, img, r, L)
    weight = bsxfun(@(a,b) getWeight(a,b,img,r,L), a, b);
end

function [weight] = getWeight(a,b,img, r, L)
    ac = num2cell(a);
    bc = num2cell(b);
    imgint1 = img(sub2ind(size(img),ac{:})); 
    imgint2 = img(sub2ind(size(img),bc{:}));
    weight = (sum((a - b) .^ 2) + (r^2/L) * abs(imgint2 - imgint1)) / (2*r^2);
end
```

My goal is to obtain an adjacency matrix that represents the distance between pixels. For the above example, the desired adjacency matrix is:

```
adjacencyMatrix =    
          0         0.2634     0.2641
          0.2634    0          0.4163
          0.2641    0.4163     0
```

Comment: Please provide a a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve In particular, values for img, R and L are missing.

Comment: @A.Donda I added values for the other parameters a 2x2 image `img =  [ 128 254; 0 255]`, `r = 3`, `L = 55`, I hope it could be clear now. I appreciate if you can help me.

Comment: Thanks, but there are still undefined variables: ac and bc. Make the code so we can reproduce your problem, but there's no other problem. :-)

Comment: @A.Donda I'm sorry for the imcomplete information. I edit in order to put de ac, bc variables. I hope It would be more clear, I really need to solve the problem.

Comment: zeellos, I still cannot reproduce your problem. Please include in your question one or more code sections corresponding to one or more m-files, that we can copy-and-paste and run, such that it leads to the error you want to solve, and *no other error*.

Comment: Btw., the `pdist` function is only fast because it relies on special efficient implementations of the distance functions. Just because you let `pdist` call your function instead of doing it in a loop won't make it any faster. Maybe it would be better if you post a question about what kind of distance you want to implement and ask about an efficient implementation, instead of asking about problems interfacing with `pdist`.

Comment: @A.Donda I added a block of code that you can copy/paste to MATLAB in order to see the error, also I put the desired result of the block of code. Thank you very much for you help.

Comment: Good, I'll have a look.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are neither fulfilling the expectations for a function to be used with `pdist`, nor those for a function to be used with `bsxfun`.

– From the documentation of `pdist`:

> A distance function must be of form
>
> d2 = distfun(XI,XJ)
>
> taking as arguments a 1-by-n vector XI, corresponding to a single row
>   of X, and an m2-by-n matrix XJ, corresponding to multiple rows of X.
>   distfun must accept a matrix XJ with an arbitrary number of rows.
>   distfun must return an m2-by-1 vector of distances d2, whose kth
>   element is the distance between XI and XJ(k,:).

However, by using `bsxfun` in `fxIntermediate`, this function always returns a *matrix* of values whose size is the larger of the sizes of the two inputs.

– From the documentation of `bsxfun`:

> A binary element-wise function of the form C
>   = fun(A,B) accepts arrays A and B of arbitrary but equal size and returns output of the same size. Each element in the output array C is
>   the result of an operation on the corresponding elements of A and B
>   only. fun must also support scalar expansion, such that if A or B is a
>   scalar, C is the result of applying the scalar to every element in the
>   other input array.

However, your `getWeight` appears to always return a scalar.

I do not understand your problem well enough in order to repair this. Moreover, I think if speed is what you are after, feeding `pdist` with a function handle is not the way to go. `pdist` does not perform magic; it is only fast because its built-in distance functions are implemented efficiently. Also, you are using anonymous function handles and conversions to and from cell arrays, all of which slow the process down. I think you should post a new question where you start with a description of what you are trying to compute, include some code that does the job even if inefficiently, and ask how to improve that.

Comment: Thank you for your help,Unfortunately, I didn't get the solution but you help me a lot. It's true that the fxIntermediate return a matrix, I would like to find one way to avoid this intermediate function. By now, I will implement a for-loop version, Thanks